# Unable to locate package openfoam221

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, package-management

While I am executing command

```
**VERS=$(lsb_release -cs)
sudo sh -c "echo deb http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu $VERS main > /etc/apt**/sources.list.d/openfoam.list"*][1]*
```

I have a file `openfoam.list`
But output of `sudo apt-get install openfoam221`
is

```
N: Ignoring file 'openfoam221_0-1_i386.deb' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'openfoamlist' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'openfoam221_0-1_i386.deb' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'openfoamlist' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'openfoam221_0-1_i386.deb' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'openfoamlist' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
E: Unable to locate package openfoam221
```

[image]

Comment: Why is there a deb file and a file in sources.list.d?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I really would love that you explain a bit what are you trying to do, but lets cleanup the mess:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openfoam*
```

Now, I'm assuming that somewhere you are typing bad something, here is how is being done:

```
sudo sh -c "echo deb http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openfoam.list"
```

Now lets check the file using `cat`:

```
braiam@bt:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openfoam.list 
deb http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu raring main
```

Now everything is ok, you can update and install whatever you want.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openfoam221
```